# Return specific value in a nested dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a nested dicitionary as the following,

```
myGame = {
          "Soccer": {
                     "T_id": 0,
                     "T_state": "valid",  
                     "Clubs": {
                                "ClubA": 
                                {
                                "T_id": "1",                                
                                "T_state": "Champs"
                                },
                                 "ClubB": 
                                {
                                "T_id": "2",                                
                                "T_state": "Runnerups"
                                }
                             },
                     "Subs": {
                                "SubA": 
                                {
                                "T_id": "3",                                
                                "T_state": "Unfit"
                                }                                
                           }
                  }
            }
```

I want to be able to return just

```
{ "T_id": 0,
  "T_state": "valid"
}
```

when I make a query to find the value associated with the key "Soccer" RATHER than returning all of the key and values in the nested dictionary. 
I tried to use the following piece of code, but it returns me the full dictionary. Can someone please guide me?

```
#note: searchkey is "Soccer" in this case and myGame is the dcitionary
    def getDic(searchkey, myGame ):
        for k in searchkey:
            myGame  = myGame .get(k)
        return myGame
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def getDic(searchkeys, myGame):
     new_dict = {}
     for key, item in myGame['Soccer'].items():
          if key in searchkeys:
               new_dict.update({key: item})
     return new_dict

searchkeys = ["T_id","T_state"]
print (getDic(searchkeys,myGame))
```

output:

```
{'T_id': 0, 'T_state': 'valid'}
```

Comment: @ncia For example, if I want to return information of the 'Clubs' and 'Subs' and not the first 'id' and 'status', how do i do that? I want to be make it generic.